# translate hql into sql with parameters binded

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

our application builds hql query dynamically based on the filters provided. Now i have a use case where i need to translate the generated hql to sql and feed that to jasper reports for report generation. here is what i was able to do so far:

translate hql to sql:

```
 private String toSql(String hql){
        QueryTranslatorFactory translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
        Session session = this.es.getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor = (SessionFactoryImplementor)session.getSessionFactory();
        Map<String,Filter> filters = getEnabledFilters(session);
        QueryTranslator translator = translatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(hql,hql,filters,sessionFactoryImplementor,null);
        translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP,false);
        return translator.getSQLString();
       }
```

Below is an example of what i get from above method:

```
select person from Person person where person.id in (?);
```

is there a way i can get "?" binded to actual values? example: (20,30) and query should look like:

```
select person from Person person where person.id in (20,30);
```

**NOTE:** : I also have filters enabled on session, i need to be able to bind those values as well.

Comment: Are you using any logger? If you using log4j you can try this property: thislog4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

Comment: I dont need the sql for logging puposes, i need it, so i can use that sql with parameters binded in jasper reports.